# How big is the update for Cataclysm after buying the digital upgrade?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

If someone was to buy Blizzard's digital upgrade version of Cataclysm, how big is the update? Also how big is the update from 4.0.1 to 4.0.3a?

Currently, I am downloading a 4.7 gig patch -- the 3.3 to 4.0.1 patch. So I am trying to find out how much more do I need to download.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not appear that Blizzard is pushing the actual Cataclysm data yet.  The data you've received so far is **just** the new version of the old world content.

Comment: I only asked because it says that you need to log in to WoW at least once after upgrading your account to Cataclysm via Blizzard's digital upgrade. It would be great if 4.0.3a or some minor patch after it officially release is need.

Comment: @Powerlord.All this data ppl are downloading is a mixture of fixes now in your current licenses/subscriptions as well as new code/content getting ready for cataclysm. But these fixes/changes are working towards the new gameplay rules and attributes which are being driven by the cataclysm release as well. Blizz do this every now and then to try and improve gameplay and keep you interested, however, I think it's getting over-tweaked.. but that's just my humble opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer is, just shy of ~900MB. Personally, I just need ~325MB to play WoW though. There was another 530MB needed. However, I was able to play after the first 325MB were downloaded.

*Note: This is my experience with the Cata updated. Might vary per person. Also, I was already at 4.0.3.1XXXX and playing before the official release of the game. The ~900MB only started downloading to my system after the official release and upgrade of my account.*

Answer (score 3):

My downloader Expect another 567MB's to complete the cataclysm update for versions going from 4.0.1 => 4.0.3. This [link](http://download.mmosite.com/html/game/23/) gives you an idea1 of patch sizes. This [page](http://download.mmosite.com/default.php?controller=resource&action=search&r_category_id=2&r_gid=23&order=addtime&page=2) tracks the 4.75GB patch from 3.3=>4. Another less helpful commentary is [here](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/1020804074) but still it provides an indication that it's in the order of hundred's of megabytes, not over a gigabyte.

The patch from 3.3 => 4.0.1 is a whopper. 4.0.1 => 4.0.3 is no where near as big. Best let your downloads run over night if you can.

Comment: Actually, the 3.3-4.0.3a updates were for the original game.  While it's happening story-wise because of the events of Cataclysm, everyone is getting this update, even if they only have the original game installed.  Blizzard will likely start streaming Cataclysm next week to people who bought it digitally.

Comment: I think you'll find that the content is still required for Cat as well. Blizz are also giving subscribers cataclysm content as a teaser to keep you all interested and "loved". Access to new instances, new level cap, and classes, races, and new class-race combo's is what you pay for. Not sure if new profession (archeology)is available to everyone.